# RVIZ start up error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a new Fuerte installation.

I am going through the PR2 Gazebo [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/BasicPR2Controls) and while trying to visualize using RVIZ, I'm receiving this error:

/home//.rviz/display_config does not exist!

I can hit the "ok" button and go in to RVIZ, but I then receive errors stating that, for instance,
No transform from [bl_caster_rotation_link] to [/map]

A similar question was asked previously, but that question was closed stating that the issue was outdated... not sure what that means... any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50730/rviz-start-up-error/) by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2012-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok. That's weird.
The error is still appearing at start up of rviz... but now it doesn't seem to be affecting anything.
I can use RVIZ now. All I did was ctrl-c out of the terminal that was running rviz, ctrl-c out of the PR2 simulation in Gazebo and then restart both.

Any ideas how to fix that display error?

---

Originally posted by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) with karma: 162 on 2012-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-01-17**:
@isaura answered this question. please give them the checkmark so it's not confusing for those looking at this question.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first issue is because you do not have a default configuration saved. You can click through it, after you have a good rviz setup do File > Save Config. This usually happens when you start rviz for the first time. If you close rviz from the gui it asks you to save the default config.

The second error is related to tfs not being generated, this is not related to the first message.

---

Originally posted by [isura](https://answers.ros.org/users/1583/isura/) with karma: 403 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3